# How to split String from json format in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm newbie at Node.js, here is my sample json format data. I want to split them into json format and need to get tid values. In node.js I tried to use JSON.parse(data) but it occured an error (becasue of [] symbols). 
is there a simple way to split them into json format and get the tid values?

```
[{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757427,"amount":90.389717,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916659},{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757428,"amount":99.428689,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916662},{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757469,"amount":384.65968,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916663}]
```

Comment: JSON.parse works perfectly fine for me, using that data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse` takes a string variable,

```json
[
    {
        "date": 1535624757,
        "date_ms": 1535624757427,
        "amount": 90.389717,
        "price": 0.00860497,
        "type": "buy",
        "tid": 251916659
    },
    {
        "date": 1535624757,
        "date_ms": 1535624757428,
        "amount": 99.428689,
        "price": 0.00860497,
        "type": "buy",
        "tid": 251916662
    },
    {
        "date": 1535624757,
        "date_ms": 1535624757469,
        "amount": 384.65968,
        "price": 0.00860497,
        "type": "buy",
        "tid": 251916663
    }
]
```

this code you goven is object variable.

you can use this

```js
var data = JSON.parse('[{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757427,"amount":90.389717,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916659},{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757428,"amount":99.428689,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916662},{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757469,"amount":384.65968,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916663}]')
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though you're trying to work with a Javascript object instead of a string that contains JSON encoded data. Consider working with the object directly.  For example, you could use a `for` loop to iterate over the elements of `data` as follows:

```js
const data =  [ {"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757427,"amount":90.389717,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916659},{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757428,"amount":99.428689,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916662},{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757469,"amount":384.65968,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916663}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i].tid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the array you posted is *not* JSON within the context of a JavaScript program (though it is a [valid standalone JSON document](https://jsonlint.com/?json=[%7B%22date%22:1535624757,%22date_ms%22:1535624757427,%22amount%22:90.389717,%22price%22:0.00860497,%22type%22:%22buy%22,%22tid%22:251916659%7D,%7B%22date%22:1535624757,%22date_ms%22:1535624757428,%22amount%22:99.428689,%22price%22:0.00860497,%22type%22:%22buy%22,%22tid%22:251916662%7D,%7B%22date%22:1535624757,%22date_ms%22:1535624757469,%22amount%22:384.65968,%22price%22:0.00860497,%22type%22:%22buy%22,%22tid%22:251916663%7D])), let's say that `data` is the value of your array:

```
const data = [{
  "date":1535624757,
  "date_ms":1535624757427,
  "amount":90.389717,
  "price":0.00860497,
  "type":"buy",
  "tid":251916659
}, {
  "date":1535624757,
  "date_ms":1535624757428,
  "amount":99.428689,
  "price":0.00860497,
  "type":"buy",
  "tid":251916662
}, { 
  "date":1535624757,
  "date_ms":1535624757469,
  "amount":384.65968,
  "price":0.00860497,
  "type":"buy",
  "tid":251916663
}];
```

You can pull out the tids like this:

```
const tids = data.map(e => e.tid);
```

tids:

```
[ 251916659, 251916662, 251916663 ]
```

If you would like tids as a JSON string, you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
const jsonTids = JSON.stringify(tids);
```

jsonTids:

```
'[251916659,251916662,251916663]'
```

Answer (score -1):

Because your JSON object is inside of an array (the [] symbol), you have to reference the JSON object by its index in the array. Like so.

```
const data = [{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757427,"amount":90.389717,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916659},{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757428,"amount":99.428689,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916662},{"date":1535624757,"date_ms":1535624757469,"amount":384.65968,"price":0.00860497,"type":"buy","tid":251916663}];

console.log(data[0]);
```

[Here's some info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections) on array's an their indexes.

Comment: Your code throws. Again, the problem is almost certainly that `JSON.parse` takes a string, you can't feed it a JavaScript data structure. Please run your code before posting it as an answer.

Comment: @JaredSmith right, you don't event have to parse it. Thanks